# How to sort each list in a list of lists

Tags: python

How can I sort the lists in the following nested list?
Function `sort` works only on normal lists.

```
lst = [[123,3,12],[89,14,2],[901,4,67]]
```

Expected result:

```
[[3,12,123],[2,14,89],[4,67,901]]
```

Answer (score 12):

This is a very straightforward way to do it without any packages (list comprehension)

```
lst_sort = [sorted(item) for item in lst]
```

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
lst = [[123,3,12],[89,14,2],[901,4,67]]

for element in lst:
    element.sort()

print(lst)
```

Loop through each item and sort separately.

Comment: This is the fastest solution, since it sorts in place. (Very superficial, quick tests on my end showed it taking about a third of the time compared to the list comprehension and functional approaches.)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a functional way to achieve this using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) as:

```
>>> lst = [[123,3,12],[89,14,2],[901,4,67]]

>>> list(map(sorted, lst))
[[3, 12, 123], [2, 14, 89], [4, 67, 901]]
```

To know more about these functions, refer:

- [`map()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [`sorted()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

Answer (score 5):

Just sort each sub list independently:

```py
lst = [[123,3,12],[89,14,2],[901,4,67]]
lst = [sorted(sub) for sub in lst]
```